# Is it possible to change language of battery status indicator?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, battery, language-support

I installed batery status indicator as the original was not really working on my HP laptop (stuck on estimating...). It is working fine but I was wondering if it is possible to change language of that indicator to any other than english.

In my case it would be polish. After installation I run update manager and usually if there is something new on my system it downloads language pack and everything is OK but in that case it didn't. It's not a problem to use english version but it would be just nicer to have everything in the same language. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that this application has simply not yet been translated into your language. As you see in the global Ubuntu 'Translations overview', there is still some work to be done for Natty. ;) https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Normally all software you install will change its language and 'follow' the users choice. For some software an additional language-pack is necessary, but your component comes with all available languages.